# geckodriver not downloading for selenium-cucumber-js

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm-install, geckodriver

Not able  to download geckodriver. Could you provide me pointers on how to debug this and fix it?

I am getting the below error message

> $> npm install geckodriver --save-dev npm WARN deprecated
>   tar.gz@1.0.5: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and
>   your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead:
>   https://npmjs.com/tar
>
> > geckodriver@1.1.2 postinstall C:\dev\regression\selenium-cucumber\node_modules\geckodriver
> >     node index.js
>
> Downloading geckodriver... events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
>       at ClientRequest. (C:\dev\regression\selenium-cucumber\node_modules\got\index.js:69:21)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! geckodriver@1.1.2
>   postinstall: `node index.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the geckodriver@1.1.2 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.

Also, is there an option to exclude a dependency in npm install?

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from here :

[geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: Yeah, I can do that manual download successfully. but I need to download it through npm install so the team can download it through the package.json dependencies..